# Cannot connect to internet after release build in Android Studio

Tags: android

I created an app using Android Studio.
It connects to the internet for various reasons
(eg. facebook SDK, Firebase database).

It's connecting OK when the app is running in a real device with build variant debug mode
but it's not connecting to the internet when the app is running in a real device with build variant release mode.

Here is my build gradle and android manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

<application
    android:name=".GenarateHashKey"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name=".StartScreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_start_screen"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".QuestionList" />
    <activity android:name=".SignInScreen" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity android:name=".ReportThisQuestionActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".UpdateQuestionlistActivity" />
</application>
```

here is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'android {
signingConfigs {
    KarateRefereeQuiz {
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.prasad.karaterefereequiz"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile files('libs/firebase-client-android-2.5.2.jar')
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `release{}` block in `buildTypes`?

Comment: I was searching soooo long for `packagingOptions { ... }`

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the lines that start with `compile files('libs/` aren't necessary when using `compile fileTree`

Comment: removed the release{} block in buildTypes but still not working :(

Comment: @xdevs23 your welcome :)

Comment: @cricket_007 i'll change that thanks for pointing that out. i didnt know that.

Comment: Yeah, that first line says "compile every JAR in the libs folder"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.facebook sdk needs realese hashkey for release builds

Answer (score 0):

From my gradle build:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {

    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

followed by dependencies, and then:

```
allprojects {
afterEvaluate { project ->
    def propsFile = rootProject.file('keystore.properties')
    def configName = 'release'

    if (propsFile.exists() && android.signingConfigs.hasProperty(configName)) {
        def props = new Properties()
        props.load(new FileInputStream(propsFile))
        android.signingConfigs[configName].storeFile = file(props['storeFile'])
        android.signingConfigs[configName].storePassword = props['storePassword']
        android.signingConfigs[configName].keyAlias = props['keyAlias']
        android.signingConfigs[configName].keyPassword = props['keyPassword']
    }
}
```

also dependencies is:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Comment: what are you suggesting sir?

Comment: Maybe edit your build file as the above is from a working, released application that has no problems connecting to the internet, and is store ready, where I think you'll find yours won't get past the post. As you asked for help, I hope it helps? Copy your original data from your build file as a back up, add the missing bits as above, and see if it works? :)

Comment: Also, if in doubt, check out what you need to do before releasing an android app, and I think you will find that the above is well documented.

Comment: Excellent, if it solves your problem you can accept the answer by clicking the tick next to it. Let me know how you get on anyway... :)

Comment: i triedyour code sir,but sadly it didnt. i downloded the firebase jar and add to android studio without online compiling.now firebase works.but not facebook.

Comment: this is my gradle now

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.0'
}

Comment: Cool, well you will need my code to release to an app store anyway, and at least you have narrowed it down to just Facebook issues. Now you only have to find out why that's not working, could it be that it needs signing with a Facebook developer ID or something similar?

Comment: This needs a Facebook app ID in your manifest file, is it correctly set in your strings?  <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

Comment: I am sure you have seen it but go through every step here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Comment: yes i did.as i mentioned,when i create debug apk every thing works.release apk that doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me.
first of all in res package create xml package and in xml package create new xml resource file with network_security_config name

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
 </network-security-config>
```

then in manifest in

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```